# matplotlib.animation: how to plot an animation and save it in a file simultaneously?

Tags: python, matplotlib

With `animation` from `matplotlib` we can plot dynamic animations. Installing the `ffmpeg` codec we can save these animations into files.

But how can I make both showing the animation while an algorithm is running and saving this animation into a file?

This code [(full snippet in this tutorial)](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/) does not work for me. It saves the file but it does not show the animation on the fly.

```
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=300,
                          interval=interval, blit=True, init_func=init)

# save the animation as an mp4.  This requires ffmpeg or mencoder to be
# installed.  The extra_args ensure that the x264 codec is used, so that    
# the video can be embedded in html5.  You may need to adjust this for
# your system: for more information, see
# http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/animation_api.html
ani.save('double_pendulum.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: That is not something that is currently supported.  Take a look at the code in `save` I suspect (but I have not looked at that code in a while) that you just need to add a line to `fig.canvas.draw()` in there  someplace.  A PR to add a kwarg to `save` to enable this behavior would be welcome.

Comment: @tcaswell can you copy your comment into an answer so that I can accept it? I'll try to make that PR.

Comment: It's not really an answer and I am not sure that it will be easy any more...

Answer (score 0):

Is the answer "not supported" still valid (i was checking the docs and searchin on the web but couldn't find a solution)?

I have the same use case where i would like to show and save an animation at the same time. Re-running the animation to save it is no option the moment one is working with dynamic, non-predictable values (i.e. for simulations using a random generator), since this will not lead to the same result.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30998122)